# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: python, mysql, django

After I installed Mysql 8.0 in mac, and changed the default root password,
I got the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` when I ran `python3 manage.py migrate` to connect MySql and init database tables, while I can login to mysql with root/new password in console without any error.

- MySql version: 8.0   <-- the key to this problem actually
- OS: macOS 10.13.4
- Python: 3.6
- Django: 1.10.3

And it's using pymysql to work with Mysql, I did lots of google and also in stackorverflow, finally I found the solution [in a CSDN tech blog](https://blog.csdn.net/m_c_ing/article/details/80412165)

Just want to share it in stackoverflow, if you also encountered this problem, you may want to try the way in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following in mysql console, to change the password encryption method to the old version in Mysql(it is changed to use cha2 in Mysql 8.0)

```
mysql -u root -p
use mysql；
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'newpassword';  
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then you should be free to run `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works when i typed every key in capital letter like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproj',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
 }
   }
```

Hope atleast it helps some noob like me.

Answer (score 0):

The `manage.py` should pick up the database access credentials from the `settings.py`, that's a specific database user (and of course that user's password as well). It's would be a security mistake to react to this error message by granting database login privileges to the local user, god forbid to the root!

The question is rather: why Django doesn't pick up the credentials from `settings.py`? In my case there were problems with the `settings.py` (we were restructuring our build pipeline from django pipeline to webpack) and I needed to remove pipeline related parts from my `settings.py` for the fix. It's a question why I didn't get any python error message about the `settings.py` problems, but instead I got this error which is not local to the real problem. That error message is just a transitive result of the source problem. Once I fixed the `manage.py`, the credentials were picked up from the DATABASE settings as usual and everything went smooth.

So the solution is to inspect and debug the `settings.py`, which is kinda hard because I don't get message about the direct error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this, I was actually trying to use a password but was accidentally setting `PASSWORD` to `None`. This explained why it was saying `using password: NO`. Make sure your `PASSWORD` isn't `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands

```
service myql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo netstat -nap | grep :80
```

If apache server is running it will show you a number before "apache2" keyword
If yes write

```
sudo kill number
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

If not

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just changing the `PASSWORD` field in the `settings.py` (DATABASES dict) to `password`.

Answer (score 0):

If root user has password that you made. Just in setting.py change 'PASSWORD': to your real password. worked for me.