# Django (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: mysql, django, nginx, ubuntu-20.04

I have come accross a strange issue, I have deployed a django site to an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server. The problem is my django app can not connect to the database because It is doesn't using the db connection credentials that have identified in app settings.py. It is using root with no password. But when I can run manage.py db operations without any problem.

This is my settings.py

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'pplus_db',
        'USER': 'pplus_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'dfa@4GL-5qQU',
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

The Error:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/login/
(1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://IP_ADDRESS/accounts/login/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652587/django-db-utils-operationalerror-1045access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: Remove the image and just paste the text output data is neccesary to describe your problem.

Comment: @Sumithran I have tried a couple of time the accepted answer of that question, but still doesn't solve my problem. May be somebody can help me understand why it doesn't use the credentials mentioned on settings.py.

Comment: Any how come the manage.py can connect to the database and the app can't?

Comment: do you have multiple settings file?

Comment: @Sumithran no just one, the default one, Its very simple django app with special functionality..

Comment: Are you sure in the server you are running the updated code, double-check it?

Comment: @Sumithran Yes I have double check, I forgot to point out the app is running on virtual envornment (venv), and every time I run manage.py I have to run it in venv. Can that be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem, I think the issue was in cashing. After follow this solution
[django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652587/django-db-utils-operationalerror-1045access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Make sure to restart your services: 
sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn 
Or if you can restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to run
`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

or reset your MySQL password to null